# Better Nagios UI?

Tags: nagios

Are there better Web UIs for Nagios than the default vanilla version that comes out of the box with Nagios?

[image]

Can some help me find a good one??

Comment: What's your definition of "better"?

Comment: Lets say "cooler"?

Comment: Define "cooler". I don't recall that being a technical term.

Comment: @John a lower operating temperature :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [Ninja](http://op5.org/community/plugin-inventory/op5-projects/ninja),

> The Ninja project is an effort to
>   develop an alternative Nagios gui with
>   the aim of being the most useful Open
>   Source web front end for Nagios.

It's currently a litte tricky to get running, but worth it and looks great. Hopefully it'll become default GUI for Nagios someday.

Comment: Ninja looks good, I think I will give it a whirl.

Answer (score 7):

With the limited dev work going in to the free version of Nagios the community fork [Icinga](http://www.icinga.org) looks very interesting.
There have a new Web UI with more features and a cleaner look as well.
There are some screenshots on this page https://www.icinga.org/screenshots/new-web/

Answer (score 2):

I've evaluated a heap of UI's and manager tools for Nagios and eventually settled on [Centreon](http://www.centreon.com/).

It's open source, has a very active development team. Installation is a wee bit involved but as long as you follow their instructions to the word then you'll be all good.

Centreon is also written in PHP, and sensible PHP too. I've already modified mine to add an audit trail of who did what and when and fixed a couple of bugs.

It also supports multiple operators and groups and has a fairly fine grained ACL config. This is great for us because we can allow our customers to login and see only their devices.

Their dev team is pretty active as well and respond to bugs in their issue tracker pretty quickly. As I said, I identified two bugs and they rolled in the changes within 24 hrs.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at these front ends hosted by Nagios: http://www.nagios.org/download/frontends

I would also take a look at Nagios LABS: http://labs.nagios.com/2011/04/14/nagios-montage/

There coming out with a new pre configured Nagios community addition called Montage

Answer (score 0):

What is really your question? Is Nagvis a solution you could be happy with?

http://www.nagvis.org/images/screenshots/nagvis_vmware.jpg for example photo.

Personally I was quite pleased with the work these guys have put into their Nagios-version. http://www.nnortux.no/

Answer (score 0):

There's lots out there - [here's a (rather old) review of 10](http://www.ducea.com/2008/01/16/10-nagios-web-frontends/) which, (IMHO, unusually) does not mention [nagvis](http://www.nagvis.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want something a little less ugly there are themes here:

http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Frontends-%28GUIs-and-CLIs%29/Web-Interfaces/Themes-and-Skins

I use (and like) the Nuvola, though I haven't tried other ones.